# How to implement a json decoder which doesn't convert numerics to double?

Tags: dart, jsonparser

When I call json.decode on financial data returned from a server, I would like to either convert my numerics to decimal (pub.dev package) (or even leave them as strings so I can manually do that later).  Everything else I would like to be converted as normal

There's a reviver callback which is passed to _parseJson(), but I can't find the implementation of this external function to study.

Update:

Looks like reviver() is too late: basic conversion has already happened by here and doubles get passed in.  Is there any alternative callback that can be used?

Comment: Indeed, but jsonDecode('{"foo": 1.01}')['foo'].runtimeType will emerge as a double and I want it as an ansi-style decimal, or as a String("1.01") which I can convert myself later. The current magic seems to be hidden inside _parseJson(), which I can't find a copy of to see if it can be overridden/replaced.

Comment: In your example, or in the reviver callback, the runtimeType of the the foo value will be double.

Comment: My mistake; you are right.  You would need to have the values explicitly quoted from the server (or if you don't control the server, you probably would need to tokenize the JSON string yourself and explicitly quote values).

Comment: However, TIL from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#cite_ref-27): "There is no inherent precision loss in serializing a machine-level binary representation of a floating-point number ...  into a human-readable decimal representation ... and back, since there exist published algorithms to do this exactly and optimally." Of course, whether Dart uses that is another story.

Comment: That's the other way round, of course. There's an ANSI representation used in Rexx and on which Java's BigDecimal is based, which indeed are lossless (in that sense anyway). Dart's double is the standard IEEE 64 bit fp and, whilst it's good, it's not good enough for financial applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [`jsontool`](https://pub.dev/packages/jsontool) package (disclaimer: I wrote it, so obviously that's what I'd turn to first).
It's a low-level JSON processor which allows you (and requires you) to take control of the processing.

It has an [example](https://github.com/lrhn/json-tool/blob/master/example/bigint_json.dart) where it parses numbers into `BigInt`s. You could probably adapt that to use `Decimal` instead.

Comment: Conversation between Lasse and myself is at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45856

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to generate a JSON parser to suit your needs.
For example from this PEG grammar.
https://github.com/mezoni/peg/blob/main/example/json.peg

All you need to do is change the semantic action code in the production rule `Number` and the result type.

```
@inline
YourType
Number_ = v:$(
  [-]?
  ([0] / [1-9][0-9]*)
  ([.] ↑ [0-9]+)?
  ([eE] ↑ [-+]? [0-9]+)?
  ) { $$ = your_conversion(v); } ;

YourType
Number = v:@expected('number', Number_) Spaces ;
```