# Decode double coming from JSON to Decimal in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, decimal, flutter-dependencies

I have a Product class in Flutter, which contains a field of type `Decimal`, using the decimal extension (https://pub.dev/packages/decimal), however the field in JSON is coming as a `float` from the server. In this way, the `jsonDecode` default method converts the value directly to `double`, which may generate some precision error. Is there any way to resolve this?

Example of my class:

```
import "package:decimal/decimal.dart";

class Product
{
    String? name;
    Decimal? price;

    Product({required this.name, required this.price});

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Product(
            name: json['name'],
            price: Decimal.tryParse(json['price']) //Error: json['price'] comes as double
        );
    }
}
```

JSON example:

```
{
    "name": "Product XXX",
    "price": 12.97
}
```

Use of default `jsonDecode` method:

```
import 'dart:convert';
//...
    Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

Comment: This question seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301697/how-to-implement-a-json-decoder-which-doesnt-convert-numerics-to-double